# System.I.O the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

I'm designing a program that calculates the average of scores. the program works great except when I try to add a name and a number from textbox into the textfile it returns an error. I believe that I have closed the file every time it has been used. my code is:

```
Public Class Form4

Public Function GetNumberOfLines(ByVal file_path As String) As Integer 

    Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\file.txt")
        Dim NumberOfLines As Integer
        Do While sr.Peek >= 0 'a pre test loop to read lines
            sr.ReadLine()
            NumberOfLines += 1
        Loop
        Return NumberOfLines
        sr.Close() 'closes file after it is read
        sr.Dispose()
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\file.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
        objWriter.Close()
        objWriter.Write(TextBox5.Text)
        MsgBox("Text written to file")
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\file.txt")
        Dim LofInt As New List(Of Integer)
        While sr.Peek <> -1
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
            Dim intValue As String = String.Empty
            For Each c As Char In line
                If IsNumeric(c) Then
                    intValue += c
                End If
            Next
            LofInt.Add(intValue)
        End While
        sr.Close()
        sr.Dispose()
        LofInt.Sort()
        For Each i In LofInt
            Scores.Items.Add(i)
        Next
        Dim sum As Decimal
        For Each decAdded As Decimal In Me.Scores.Items
            sum += Double.Parse(decAdded)
        Next
        TextBox4.Text = sum
        sr.Close()
        sr.Dispose()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt")
    TextBox2.Text = GetNumberOfLines("C:\file.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sum As Decimal
    Dim avg As Decimal
    For Each decAdded As Decimal In Me.Scores.Items
        sum += Double.Parse(decAdded)
    Next
    avg = sum / (GetNumberOfLines("C:\file.txt")) 
    TextBox3.Text = avg
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    Scores.Items.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt")
    TextBox2.Text = GetNumberOfLines("C:\file.txt")
    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\file.txt")
        Dim LofInt As New List(Of Integer)
        While sr.Peek <> -1
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
            Dim intValue As String = String.Empty
            For Each c As Char In line
                If IsNumeric(c) Then
                    intValue += c
                End If
            Next
            LofInt.Add(intValue)
        End While
        LofInt.Sort()
        For Each i In LofInt
            Scores.Items.Add(i)
        Next
        Dim sum As Decimal
        For Each decAdded As Decimal In Me.Scores.Items
            sum += Double.Parse(decAdded)
        Next
        TextBox4.Text = sum
        sr.Close()
        sr.Dispose()
    End Using
End Sub
```

`Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)` is where the error occurs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add "thanks" and other text not directly related to problem (like "new to C#, site,...") to questions. If you feel that thank you are important to your question - please discuss it first on http://meta.stackoverflow.com (but consider reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it first). Also avoid adding unrelated tags - this is not C/VBA/C# - unless you are looking for quick downvotes.

Comment: There's a fair bit of code there and some of it is a bit nonsensical when it comes to reading and writing files.  Firstly, get rid of all calls to `Close` or `Dispose` on a `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter`.  Next, make sure that every `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` is created with a `Using` statement.  The object will then be automatically disposed, and the file closed, at the `End Using` line, even if an exception is thrown.  As long as you don't have nested `Using` blocks, you'll never have an issue with files not being closed when you want to open them.